# how to append an array to another arrays in php

Tags: php

I have to arrays in script

```
    $users = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
    $newUsers = array("F", "G", "H", "I");
    $totalUsers = $users + $newUsers;
```

By using Union operator, I tried to append **$newUser** array to **$users**.

And store it in **$totalUsers**, after printing the **$totalUsers** by using **print_r($totalUsers)**.

It printed out only the **$users** array contents.
Why ?

I used the **array_merge($users + $newUsers)** and also it printed only the **$users** array contents.

Finally by using one of the following methods,

**method 1:**

```
    $totalUsers = array_merge(array_values($users), array_values($newUsers));
    print_r($totalUsers);
```

**method 2:**

```
    array_merge($users, $newUsers);
    print_r($totalUsers);
```

I got the correct output

```
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
    [5] => F
    [6] => G
    [7] => H
    [8] => I
)
```

What was the problem, and what is different between the above methods??

Answer (score 3):

> The `+` operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.
>
> http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.array.php

In other words, it only adds elements from the right hand if the keys don't already exist in the left hand array. That explains why it does nothing in your case.

```
array_merge($users + $newUsers)
```

This does exactly the same, an array union, and afterwards does an `array_merge` on the result. So it does nothing either.

```
array_merge($users, $newUsers)
```

This does exactly what you want, it's the correct thing to do.

```
array_merge(array_values($users), array_values($newUsers))
```

This does the exact same thing as well, `array_values` does nothing in this case.

Comment: Brilliant, but would you tell me when is `array_values` useful?

Comment: `array_values` resets all array keys to continuously numerically indexed keys. You already have that in this case. http://php.net/array_values

Answer (score 1):

```
$totalUsers = array_merge($users, $newUsers);
```

That is the correct way to use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). You can also input more then two arrays to be merged.

EDIT: To read more on the array operators, please visit this link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: Yes it is OK, but I want to know what is wrong and different between the last to methods?

Comment: "The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored." - PHP Manual